# Count words in different sections of a text file

Tags: python, text-mining

for a project I have to analyze a txt file with over 200 resumes in it with python. I have to search trough the file and have to count if a specific key is mentioned. This is my very easy code:

```py
file = open("CVC.txt")

data=file.read()

occurence = data.count("Biology")

print('Number of occurrences of the word :', occurence)
```

The problem is when I search for e.g. Enginnering it is mentioned several times in one CV. But I just want to count it once. Every resume starts with the word 'contact'. My question is how can I specify an Algorithm that can differentiate between the resumes and only counts for a specific keyword ones in the cv.

Thanks in advance!

[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUHvN.png)
[ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo1UU.png)

Comment: Can a resume contain the word "contact" a second time? You need to have a clear way of detecting the beginning and ends of resumes in your text file.

Comment: You should show us an example of the file in the post. Please [edit]

Comment: @Stef Each VC only contains the word "contact" ones. Then all the information about the person is listed where I want to detect a word. The word I want to detect can occur multiple times, but I only want to count it one time. Then after this CV the next one comes and also starts with "contact" and it has to be searched again and then the next one comes etc.... With the word contact I can check pretty reliable the start of the resume and then with the next contact i can detect that this resume has ended and a new one comes

Comment: @OneCricketeer In my comment I described the structure pretty precise:) Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of the actual file

Comment: @OneCricketeer i did :)

Answer (score 1):

The logic is somewhat straightforward. Parse each line of the file, when you see a line that starts a contact, then store the line and all after until you see the next contact line. When the file is done being read, store the remaining lines as part of the last started contact.

```
contacts = []
current_contact = None

with open("CVC.txt") as data:

    for line in data.splitlines():
      # skip page lines (e.g. in middle of a contact)
      if line.strip().startswith("Page "):
        continue
      # start a new contact
      if line.strip() == "Contact":
        if current_contact is not None:
          # store the current contact lines, if they exist
          contacts.append('\n'.join(current_contact))
        current_contact = []
        continue
      # collect all lines for a single contact
      if current_contact is not None:
        current_contact.append(line.rstrip())
      else:
        print(f"Not seen 'Contact' yet... '{line.rstrip()}'")  # for debugging, e.g. start of the file
    # store remaining data after all lines are read
    if current_contact:
      contacts.append('\n'.join(current_contact))
      del current_contact
```

I made an example file like this

```
Contact

https://linkedin.com/1

Fugit dicta voluptates iusto. Aut nam iste impedit. A aliquam repellendus consectetur esse vero placeat doloremque. Necessitatibus est labore provident atque possimus

Page 1 of 2

Hic dignissimos consequatur error.

Contact

https://linkedin.com/2

Fugit dicta voluptates iusto. Aut nam iste impedit. A aliquam repellendus consectetur esse vero placeat doloremque. Necessitatibus est labore provident atque possimus. Hic dignissimos consequatur error.
```

And this test output

```
>>> for c in contacts:
...   print(c.splitlines())
... 
['', 'https://linkedin.com/1', '', 'Fugit dicta voluptates iusto. Aut nam iste impedit. A aliquam repellendus consectetur esse vero placeat doloremque. Necessitatibus est labore provident atque possimus', '', '', 'Hic dignissimos consequatur error.']
['', 'https://linkedin.com/2', '', 'Fugit dicta voluptates iusto. Aut nam iste impedit. A aliquam repellendus consectetur esse vero placeat doloremque. Necessitatibus est labore provident atque possimus. Hic dignissimos consequatur error.']
```

To count words in one contact, you can access by the position

```
contacts[0].count("Biology")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with simpler logic, create a flag that tells if 1. We are inside a contact and 2. if we have already seen that word in this contact.

```
counter = 0 
is_counted = True # Initialize the flag to avoid the code breaking
word = 'engineering' # Change this
with open('cv.txt','r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        if "contact" in line.lower():
            is_counted = False
        elif is_counted == False and word in line.lower():
            counter += 1
            is_counted = True
        line = file.readline()

print(counter)
```

I have tried it on a small sample successfully, try it on your input and see if it works.

Comment: it somehow does not work

Comment: Does it not work at all or produce a wrong output?

Comment: it always says 0

Comment: Did you make sure to change the variable `word` to the word you are looking for? If yes, then write it in all lower, don't capitalize any letters, or replace all instances of `line.lower()` with just `line` .

Comment: okay thanks now it works! How do I alter the code if for example the first line can start with contact or kontakt ?

Comment: You can change the first if condition, either change the word `contact` or if both words can exist you can add an `or` like : `if "contact" in line.lower() or "Kontakt" in line.lower():`